# Substract dataframes with different timestamp in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two dataframes with the same index

```
(df1)                          (df2)
Timestamp    A                Timestamp     B
01:00        1                01:00         2
02:00        2                02:00         3
03:00        3                03:00         4
```

How can I subtract df1[i] - df2[i-1]? Because it will automatically subtract 2 rows with same index.

Wanted result:

```
Timestamp   C
01:00       NaN
02:00       0
03:00       0
```

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame.shift` will shift the index by the specified number of periods so you can align row `i` with row `i-1` in the other DataFrame. (Make sure `'Timestamp'` is your index.)

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3]}, 
                   index=pd.Index(['01:00', '02:00', '03:00'], name='TimeStamp'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': [2,3,4]}, 
                   index=pd.Index(['01:00', '02:00', '03:00'], name='TimeStamp'))
```

---

```
(df1['A'] - df2['B'].shift()).to_frame('C')

             C
TimeStamp     
01:00      NaN
02:00      0.0
03:00      0.0
```